# Java Future vs c# async await

Tags: java, c#-4.0, asynchronous

Im a c# developer and now started transitioning to Java...and started comparing the features

i came across this Future in Java concurrency
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkkqg.html
As per the documentation example it says 
**Even if the payment processor takes a long time, the client can continue working, and display the result when the processing finally completes.**

So can we assume Future is same as c# async await..if not please lemme know the difference...

As per my knowledge sync ,await i have used in mobile operations where we 
didnt want the UI thread  to be blocked while it interacts with apis or service.

Comment: No, Java the language does not have a feature like async await in C#.

Answer (score 3):

`Future` is just an interface. It is not capable of handling anything asynchronously by itself. You receive a `Future` object when you submit some work to be executed asynchronously in an `ExecutorService`. Use `Future.get()` to block the current thread until the result is ready. Of course you should do something useful in the current thread between the time you submit the work and try to get the result.

Comment: if it blocks the main thread then howcome the call becomes asynchronous.please correct me if im wrong..

Comment: And the doc says "the client can continue working, and display the result when the processing finally completes"

Comment: The call only becomes asynchronous because when you hand off the work (Callable) to an ExecutorService, it is executed in another thread.

Answer (score 0):

Java Future is not equivalent to C# async/await. Simply it is the result of an asynchronous task (running in a different thread) that can be awaited in the main thread.
When calling a method returning Future, that method will be executed in a different thread and when the result is needed in the caller thread you can block that thread with Future.get().

While C# async/await doesn't imply using a different thread. It only suspends the enclosing method and returns the execution to the caller method where both methods can be executed in the same thread.